# Pass event options to on:event directive

Tags: event-handling, dom-events, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Is it possible to pass event options to a svelte `on:*` directive?

To register an event listener with options I currently use:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from "svelte"
  
  let root: HTMLElement

  onMount(() => {
    const touchHandlerOptions = {
      passive: true,
    }

    root.addEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart, touchHandlerOptions)
  })
</script>

<div bind:this={root} />
```

Wondering if this could be refactored to pass the options in an `on:*` directive directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to pass options directly, but you can use event-modifiers:

```html
<div on:touchstart|passive={handleTouchStart}>
```

[See docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-on-eventname)